# how to add office365 credentials in get request to retrieve list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

here is simple service function getting list items;

```
public readItems(webUrl: string, listName: string): ng.IPromise<IListItem[]> {
    const deferred: ng.IDeferred<IListItem[]> = this.$q.defer();

    this.$http({
      url: `${webUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items`,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
      }
    }).then((result: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<{ value: IListItem[] }>): void => {
      deferred.resolve(result.data.value);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

I am to to see contents of list in browser using same url;
[image]

but in application response to this call;
[image]

how can I add required information that sharepoint needs to understand its authenticated request?

Comment: See SO Post: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203953/access-sharepoint-online-data-using-adal-js-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd not be surprised your JavaScript code runs from another domain than `mod970274.sharepoint.com`, thus resulting in a [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) violation... and cross-domain calls being forbidden by default result in a *403* error, as the one you get...

Fortunately, with Office 365, there's now a way to workaround this policy by declaring an app in the Office 365 portal (the app declaration includes the domain name your JavaScript code is hosted at); calls from this app will then be allowed by the mean of "CORS".
Official info can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-web-apps-using-cors-to-access-files-in-office-365) + a lot of [other articles](https://www.google.fr/search?q=office%20365%20cors%20sharepoint%20api).